How can I call storefront api and admin api from app embeds liquid file in shopify?
I want to call the storefront api from my apps app embed which is a liquid file.
And for some queries I also need to call the admin api and I know for that I need to use the app proxy.
But what I'm confused about is how can I make these calls from the liquid file.
Thanks!
